# How to copy vertex or edge pattern from one place to another

Tags: modeling, edges, vertex-groups

Please guide me if there is any way to copy vertex or edge pattern from one place to another.Because I need to get the same size and pattern and have to do multiple points and I can't use mirror because each position is not symmetrical.

Please guide me if there is any way I can make it work faster. Thank you

[image]

Comment: select vertices then press `Shift+D` doesnt do the job?

Comment: Shift - D This creates an identical copy of the selected object. But I want to connect the vertex to the workpiece. Do You have some way to guide me after Shift D ? Thanks for your answer. @Harry McKenzie

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is put a circle where that vertex is, then you want to bevel it instead of manually moving that geometry there:
[image]

Select the vertex you want rounded (You can select multiple of them)
Then hit Ctrl+Shift+B to bevel it. By default it will not be a circle but a cross. Adjust the Shape setting to around 0.085 in the popup window to make it round.
The switch to Face select mode, this will have all those faces selected, and click Ctrl+X to merge them.

Then with all the round faces selected you can inset them by pressing I. Do this twice to get the same shape you have there on all the vertices

Comment: The above method is how to create a circle. But if doing it one vertex at a time, it will be very delayed. please suggest me how to copy the circle somewhere else? By having to connect the vertex into the same workpiece  can you guide me?

thanks for the answer I got some additional tips from your answer.  @Cornivius

Comment: You can do the above method with all the vertices selected that you want at once.

Comment: You can also just turn on 'snap mode' (Magnet icon in the top middle of the workspace) with the Vertex option selected in the drop menu next to it. Then select the geometry you want copied, duplicate it with shift+D and while it's moving hit Shift+Z so it doesn't move up or down (Shift+X or Shift+Y if this is not a top down view). It will then snap to the vertices as you move it over them. This lets you place that exact geometry on top of that vertex but you are still gonna have to delete the vertex and connect it manually. This will be a lot more work if you have multiple vertices tho

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't do it from the start. I don't select all the veritices But I follow your instructions. Thanks for the answer You made me gain more knowledge from this question. Thanks a lot. @Cornivius